# Does energy produce a gravitational force

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, energy

$E=mc^2$.

From this, I would assume that any form of energy (not just rest-mass energy, but kinetic energy as well) would produce a gravitational force.  Am I being too naive in my application of this equation, or is this a real thing?

I haven't made a formal study of General Relativity, but I do seem to recall from what I have learned about it that all forms of energy come in to the stress-energy tensor, which means that all forms of energy would also have an effect on the geometry of space, thus "energy would produce a gravitational force".

Comment: Duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130552/how-can-gravity-affect-light, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107808/does-non-matter-energy-curve-spacetime, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22876/does-a-photon-exert-a-gravitational-pull, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103918/what-are-the-factors-affecting-the-spacetime-curvature, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92293/gravity-from-energy, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62390/does-non-mass-energy-generate-a-gravitational-field

Comment: I won't vote to close, but i think my answer to [Intuitive understanding of the elements in the stress-energy tensor](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184042/intuitive-understanding-of-the-elements-in-the-stress-energy-tensor) goes a long way towards answering your question.

Comment: The duplicates I was pointed to answered my question.